The problem in my Flutter project's .tt file is due to a change in line order or some lines unintentionally. What is the solution, please?
Launching lib\main.dart on RMX3627 in debug mode...
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/debug.dart:337:60: Error: Undefined name 'ErrorWidget'.
            throw FlutterError.fromParts(<DiagnosticsNode>[ErrorWidget.builder]);has occurred.
                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/debug.dart:337:82: Error: 'has' isn't a type.
            throw FlutterError.fromParts(<DiagnosticsNode>[ErrorWidget.builder]);has occurred.
                                                                                 ^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/debug.dart:337:86: Error: Expected ';' after this.
            throw FlutterError.fromParts(<DiagnosticsNode>[ErrorWidget.builder]);has occurred.
                                                                                     ^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/debug.dart:337:94: Error: Expected an identifier, but got '.'.
Try inserting an identifier before '.'.
            throw FlutterError.fromParts(<DiagnosticsNode>[ErrorWidget.builder]);has occurred.
                                                                                          ^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/debug.dart:338:36: Error: Expected ',' before this.
            FlutterError (Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.
                                   ^^^^^^^^

"The following errors appeared when running the application."

"I tried cleaning the package folder and updating Flutter's version, but to no avail. I also tried creating a new project, but the same problem persists."
